# Difference of Tangents

Tags: trigonometry

Express the $\tan(\arcsin(u) - \arccos(v))$ algebraically containing $u$ and $v$, but without using trig functions.

I know that in order to express this I need to use the Difference of Tangents Formula, but I don't know quite how to figure out the $\cos()$ associated with $u$, and the $\sin()$ associated with $v$ based on the given values to be able to write the tangent as a fraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) of  principal value of inverse trigonometric functions,

If $\arcsin(u)=x\implies u=\sin x;-\dfrac\pi2\le x\le\dfrac\pi2\implies\cos u\ge0$

$\implies\cos u=+\sqrt{1-\sin^2u}=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

$\implies\tan u=\dfrac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\implies\arctan\dfrac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=u$

Again if $\arccos(v)=y\implies\cos y=v$ and $0\le y\le\pi\implies\sin y\ge0$

$\implies\sin y=+\sqrt{1-v^2}$

$\implies\tan y=\dfrac{\sqrt{1-v^2}}v\implies y=\arctan\dfrac{\sqrt{1-v^2}}v$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\tan(\arcsin u)=\dfrac{\sin(\arcsin(u))}{\cos(\arcsin (u))}=\dfrac{u}{\pm\sqrt{1-u^2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $\sin x = u$ then $\tan x = \pm \cfrac {u}{\sqrt {1-u^2}}$

Answer (score 0):

use that $\tan(x-y)=\frac{\tan(x)-\tan(y)}{1+\tan(x)\tan(y)}$
the result is 
${\frac {uv-\sqrt {-{v}^{2}+1}\sqrt {-{u}^{2}+1}}{\sqrt {-{v}^{2}+1}u+v
\sqrt {-{u}^{2}+1}}}
$

Comment: What if $v=-\dfrac12$ ??

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to imagine this is to draw a right angled triangle for each of the angles. e.g. for $arcsin(u)$ you know that you need an angle (say $\theta$) which has the property $\sin(\theta)=u$. You then then use pythagorus to determine the missing side in this triangle as shown below:
[image]

You can then use this to determine the other trigonometric functions - e.g.:$$\cos(\theta)=\sqrt{1-u^2}$$$$\tan(\theta)=\frac{u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$$